# Why did my character data get corrupted?

Tags: dead-island

One time that I log into Dead Island, hit PLAY at the title menu to look at my character data, and look at characters data, one of my character data is corrupted. Instead of the facial icon for the character, it's like an anonymous, gray silhouette, and instead of the time-stamp info of the last time that I played them, it said something like "CORRUPTED". I can't play it anymore; All I can do with it is delete it.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/622414-dead-island/60399291) thread, it's due to file size. So, I guess that if you want to avoid corruption, you must hoard less.

More sources: http://www.deadislandforums.com/showthread.php/3173-IMPORTANT!-How-to-Avoid-SAVE-Corruption!!